# Stuck on setting up system of equations problem: firm with four goods that use 3 inputs

Tags: linear-programming

I'm having trouble setting up this problem.
A  firm  produces  4  kinds  of  goods:  G1, G2,G3,G4. Each good requires  three  kinds  of  input:
Labor, Row Materials, Capital (quantity if each input needed for each good is noted in the table below)
There  are  14  units  of  Labor,  15  units  of  row  materials,  and  10  units  of  capital.
Find 
quantity of each good if all inputs are utilized in these goods production.
G1 uses 3 L, 2 RM, 1 C
g2 uses 2 L, 5 RM, 2 C
g3 uses 2 L , 2 RM, 2 C
g4 uses 1 L, 3 RM, 3 C

I know that each good is a sum of inputs and the question is asking how many of each good can I produce using all the inputs. Any help or suggestion on setting up this problem will be appreciated

Comment: If you sell $g_1$ amount of good type $1$, how much labor is used in the process?  $3g_1$, right?  If you sell $g_2$ amount of good type $2$, how much labor is used for this?  Continuing, how much labor is used **total** from the perspective of how much of each good we used?  What does the problem statement tell us about how much labor we use?  This gives us a first equation, $3g_1+2g_2+2g_3+1g_4=14$.  Do so similarly for the remaining two kinds of input.  Solve the corresponding system via gaussian elimination.  Finally, make sure any answer (or answers) make sense (non-negative, integer,...)

Comment: I began setting up the equation up that way and I wanted to see if I was on the right track. Thank you for answering my question